# Librerias necesarias para carrusel de imagenes Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Tengo un archivo php en el cual quiero mostrar un carrusel de imagenes sencillo, pero lo que no funciona son las animaciones de transicion al momento de cambiar de imagen, hice algunas pruebas y descubrí que cuando importo el archivo CSS de bootstrap descargado no funciona, es este:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
```

Pero en cambio cuando importo el archivo css desde el servidor de bootstrap, si funciona la transicion ¿Alguien me podría ayudar a saber que sucede y como solucionarlo? Muchas gracias de ante mano, lo importo desde la pagina, así

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Hola @Giovanni, seguramente en tu navegador puedes asegurarte primero si estás descargando el archivo con seguridad (en las opciones de desarrolladores, en network o red) Es posible que no estés consiguiendo linkarlo cuando está en local, o que se trate simplemente de otra versión. Lo has comprobado?

Comment: Se está linkeando bien, además de que aparecen las fuentes y todo de bootstrap, lo que desaparece es la animación de transicion

Comment: Creo que tiene que ver algo de un tal Bootstrap CDN

Comment: Inicialmente, no parece que sean los mismos archivos. Si lo fueran, es extraño que se comporte diferente. Si se están comportando diferente, te diría que revises la cabecera del fichero local para asegurarte que es la versión `4.4.1`

Comment: Acabo de ver y son las mismas versiones :( Solo necesito esa animacion :'(

Comment: De momento tu ejemplo no es verificable, así que poco podemos ayudarte. Intenta añadir las partes necesarias de tu código  para que podamos ayudarte. 

Puedes crear un script (Hay un botón para añadir snippets) , o un jsfiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Date cuenta de que **Bootstrap** es una librería que depende totalmente de **JQuery**, sin ella no vas a poder usar muchas de sus funcionalidades. En las cargas que nos muestras no veo por ningún lado archivos **.js** solamente **css**. Cuando se usa una librería hay que tener muy en cuenta sus dependencias y lo que necesitas cargar para que esta funcione, esto lo podemos obtener en su documentación: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/